# Spring MVC custom event which extends ApplicationEvent called twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've done a user registration email confirmation in my Spring app, based on this tutorial http://www.baeldung.com/registration-verify-user-by-email

Having a strange problem. for unknown reason, my custom event always fired 2 times.

Here is the code:
**event:**

```
public class OnRegistrationCompleteEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private final String appUrl;
    private final Locale locale;
    private final User user;

    public OnRegistrationCompleteEvent(User user, Locale locale, String appUrl) {
        super(user);

        this.user = user;
        this.locale = locale;
        this.appUrl = appUrl;
    }

    public String getAppUrl() {
        return appUrl;
    }
    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

**listener:**

```
@Component
public class RegistrationListener implements ApplicationListener<OnRegistrationCompleteEvent> {

    private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RegistrationListener.class.getName());


    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(OnRegistrationCompleteEvent event) {
        this.confirmRegistration(event);
    }

    private void confirmRegistration(OnRegistrationCompleteEvent event) {
        logger.info("OnRegistrationCompleteEvent confirmSocialPosting fired");
        final User user = event.getUser();

        String recipientAddress = user.getEmail();
        String subject = "Registration Confirmation";
        String from = "contactblablabla@gmail.com";

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = null;
        try {
            helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, false, "utf-8");
            String htmlMsg = "Your account was successfully registered! <br><br>" +
                    "username: "+user.getUsername()+"<br>"+
                    "password: "+user.getPassword()+"<br>";

            mimeMessage.setContent(htmlMsg, "text/html");
            helper.setTo(new InternetAddress(recipientAddress));
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            logger.error("Message creation exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public JsonResponse AddUser(@RequestBody @Valid User user, WebRequest request) throws SQLException {
        String result = userService.RegisterUser(user);
        if(result.equals("done")) {
            try {
                String appUrl = request.getContextPath();
                eventPublisher.publishEvent(new OnRegistrationCompleteEvent(user, request.getLocale(), appUrl));
            } catch (Exception me) {
                return new JsonResponse("FAIL", "Unknown on event publishing: "+ me.getMessage());
            }
            return new JsonResponse("OK", "");

        } else if(result.equals("duplicate")) {
            return new JsonResponse("FAIL", "duplicate");
        }
        return new JsonResponse("FAIL", "Unknown");
}
```

So, in my log, i have `OnRegistrationCompleteEvent confirmSocialPosting fired` 2 times. And 2 emails send. What is the problem can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is cause because it to register twice. You are using anotation in your application i.e base-package="com.example"
thats why it registering twise

**Remove anotation @component from your listener class and define bean defination in .xml file**

this wokrs!!

Comment: Wow! Right, as i remember - solved by something like that :) Forgot to post a solution here.